# Wordpress get result from title (anywhere), not just first word

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Currently this is working code that is queried as standalone search.php.

I have an issue that it searches beginning of title and not anywhere in title what I exactly need.

I have a feeling that I'm close to solution and I tried couple of things and it is probably something that I'm missing in post $args..

```
global $wp_query;
$type = 'qa';
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
      'showposts'=>100,
      'orderby'=> 'menu_order',
      'order' => 'DESC'
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
$data = array();
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
      $title = get_the_title();
      $url = get_the_permalink();
      $data[$title] = $url;
  endwhile;
}

if(isset($_POST['latestQuery'])){
 $latestQuery = $_POST['latestQuery'];
 $latestQueryLength = strlen($latestQuery);
 $result = array();
 foreach($data as $name => $url){
   if (substr(strtolower($name),0,$latestQueryLength) == strtolower($latestQuery)){
       $result[$name] = $url;
   }
 }
 echo json_encode($result);
}
```

This is already working in local environment.

JavaScript queries search.php file (above) where it gets json array returned based on query... for example "cla.."

```
{"Classic something":"http:\/\/www.something\/qa2","Classic something else":"http:\/\/www.something\/qa"}
```

So I have properly retuned two items that only have "Classic" mentioned in post title.

If I type "som" or "els" it doesn't return anything and it should match as well all "some" and "else" items.

I think it is not an issue with javascript code but with PHP code.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to create a custom search?

Comment: Hi ThemesCreator. I just updated main post as I can't format comment.

Answer (score 0):

Solved if would be helpful to someone in future.

```
if(isset($_POST['latestQuery'])){
 $latestQuery = $_POST['latestQuery'];


global $wp_query;
$type = 'qa';
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  's' => "$latestQuery", // defined query
      'showposts'=>100,
      'orderby'=> 'menu_order',
      'order' => 'DESC',
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
$data = array();
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
      $title = get_the_title();
      $url = get_the_permalink();
      $data[$title] = $url;
  endwhile;
}

 $result = array();
 foreach($data as $name => $url){ // removed if
       $result[$name] = $url;
 }
 echo json_encode($result);
}
```